# Script for modifying behavior of running C program

Tags: c, bash, cmd, exec

I have a situation where I submitted jobs that have been running for five days but due to a bug introduced all the work could be lost. I made a 'system' call to compress the data file and then remove the original uncompressed file that could be as big as 4G. So I have this in the C code

```
    strcpy(command,"data"); ////I should added a forward slash here "data/"
    sprintf(command,"%scompress -c -i %s -o %s",command,name,out_name);
    system(command);
    remove(name); /////This is the problem
```

The bug is in the sprintf line, in which what I wanted to do was to call a program in data/compress, but due to the missing '/' the system command fails. And thus the data produced is not compressed AND then immediately the original file is DELETED leaving me with nothing! If it was compressed it would have been OK.

There are currently five running jobs in such a state. I need to divert this behavior somehow so that I don't lose five days work. I am thinking to  create a fake script named 'datacompress' in the current directory to change the behavior of the running program. Can I do this or are there better options, if at all?

Comment: Two tips: Don't use the same buffer as both source and destination in `sprintf`, you don't know in which order the function will write to your buffer. The second is to use `snprintf` instead, to avoid possible buffer overflows.

Comment: Another tip - Update your CV!

Comment: I think it may be my bad use of sprintf that caused the problem. Even though I wrote a strcpy with "data" to demonstrate the missing forward slash, I actually initialized it to 'data/' but somehow the slash got lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `datacompress` a symbolic link to `data/compress`. Oops, this won't work unless the process's `$PATH` includes `.`.

Another option: remove the user's write permission to the directory containing `name`. This will cause the `remove()` function to fail.

If your system has Access Control Lists, remove the process's delete permission on the uncompressed file.

While you're trying to come up with a solution, you can suspend the process with:

```
kill -STOP <pid>
```

Comment: Ok I added the symbolic link by "ln -s data/compress datacompress". Hope it works. But I can not seem to execute it like a script, if symbollinks are meant work like that. I can not change user permissions because other jobs that are working with previous version of the exe are still running. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Just realized that it probably won't work. If a command name doesn't contain `/`, it's searched in `$PATH`. So unless `.` is in `$PATH`, it won't execute a command in the current directory.

Comment: Unfortunately programs finished now but thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Create hard links (*not* symbolic links) to the data files:

```
ln datafile datafile.bkp
```

When the program removes the original datafile, the file's contents will remain under the .bkp filename.

And then fix the program to check error status of important things like the compress command.